# How to find out the tenant name using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-management-api, azure-management

Is there an API that can be used to get the tenant name where a resource is? I know the resource group and the subscription.

All that I found so far is a way to list all the tenants https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2017-08-01 but i still don't know how to connect this info with an Azure resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, if you want to use rest api to do that, seems we could just use the MS graph api : [Get organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) or the AAD graph `GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant id}/tenantDetails?api-version=1.6`  to get the tenant name, but it just get the currently authenticated tenant.

If you want to the tenant name via a resource, you could use azure powershell to do that. As you know the subscription, specific the `-SubscriptionId`  with which subscription the resource in.

```
$TenantId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxxx").TenantId
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId
Get-AzureADTenantDetail
```

[image]

The `DisplayName` is the tenant name.

Answer (score 0):

The main endpoint is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization

Sample code (Node.js):

```
const info_tenant = await apiRequestFunction(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization`, 'GET', null, {
      "Authorization": access_token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
});
```

returns organisation information where `info_tenant.value[0].displayName` is tenant name.